# Computing the adjoint of a mapping using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $D:\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$ be the
>   derivative function and consider the scalar product defined by:
>   $<p(x)\,,\,q(x)>=\int_{-1\,}^{1}p(x)\,q(x)\,dx$. Find $D^{*},$ the
>   adjoint of $D$.

I've solved this problem using the definition of adjoint, $\forall v,w\in\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]\,:\,<D(v)\,,\,w>=<w\,,\,D^{*}(w)>$,
but I'd like to solve it using matrices. My problem is that I can't
compute the matrix associated with $D$. I already have an orthornormal
basis $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x,(x^{2}-\frac{1}{3})\sqrt{\frac{45}{8}}\}$,
obtained using the Gram-Schmidt process. Could you please provide
any hint?

Comment: To get the matrix (call it $A$) associated with $D$, you would compute the images of your basis, to conclude $D^*$, you would do the reverse by looking at $A^T$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $D\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)=0$, $D\left(\sqrt{\frac32}x\right)=\sqrt{\frac32}$, and $D\left((x^2-1)\sqrt{\frac{45}8}\right)=3\sqrt{\frac52}x$, the matrix of $D$ with respect to your basis is$$\begin{pmatrix}0&\sqrt3&0\\ 0&0&\sqrt{15}\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$Can you do the rest now?

Comment: Yes professor. My problem was that using the def. of adjoint we used the basis $(1,x,x^2)$ so of course both matrices were different.